# Alerting Opera users to change settings to support Font Awesome

Tags: javascript, if-statement, alert, opera

My website uses Font Awesome which doesn't show in Opera Mobile when Off-Rode mode is on, so I want to alert people that they should turn it off or use different browser.

Can you please tell me what I do wrong or if you know better way to alert?

```
if(window.opera) {
    if (!document.cookie.match(/(?:^|; *)alert_shown=1/)) {
        document.cookie = "alert_shown=1;max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24;
    }
    alert("Turn off Off-Road mode, please");  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the alert inside the second `if`. Otherwise it will be shown all the time, regardless of the cookie.

```
if(window.opera) {
    if (!document.cookie.match(/(?:^|; *)alert_shown=1/)) {
        document.cookie = "alert_shown=1;max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24;
        alert("Turn off Off-Road mode, please");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar is right although I prefer this. It's Neater!

```
if (window.opera && !document.cookie.match(/(?:^|; *)alert_shown=1/)) {
  document.cookie = "alert_shown=1;max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24;
  alert("Turn off Off-Road mode, please");  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Enclose the string inside alert in quotes.

```
alert("some string here");
alert('more strings here');
```